# Ignite 2.10.0 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "LOCK_MODE" not found

Tags: h2, ignite

Recently, I upgraded the ignite version  from 2.7 to 2.10.0. Since then my test IT with @SpringbootTest cases are failing.
I am using h2 version 1.4.197 in the pom as h2.version.
The upgrade to 1.4.200 didn't solve my problem

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "LOCK_MODE" not found; SQL statement:
CALL LOCK_MODE() [90022-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readJavaFunction(Parser.java:2699)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFunction(Parser.java:2756)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:3102)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2587)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2574)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2544)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2370)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2342)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2334)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseCall(Parser.java:4854)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:382)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:307)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1251)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.getTransactionIsolation(JdbcConnection.java:815)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDefaultIsolation(PoolBase.java:479)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.checkDriverSupport(PoolBase.java:442)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:410)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:363)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    ... 151 more
```

Thank you for your help. I have been trying to solve this problem for a while but with no luck

Comment: Hi please edit your post, so it will also contain your SQL query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Were you able to solve it ?

Comment: i used 1.4.197 with 2.10.0 and the problem was with my integration test that execute all together. DirtiesContext solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Function in h2 core will add these methods in static block, but somehow the function map has missed something, didn't know why, at least in my case it will work when I add the following code(JDK11):

```
try {
     Field functionInfos = Function.class.getDeclaredField("FUNCTIONS");
     functionInfos.setAccessible(true);
     var lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Field.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
     VarHandle modifiers = lookup.findVarHandle(Field.class, "modifiers", int.class);
     int mods = functionInfos.getModifiers();
     if (Modifier.isFinal(mods)) {
         modifiers.set(functionInfos, mods & ~Modifier.FINAL);
     }
     HashMap map = (HashMap) functionInfos.get(null);
     System.out.println(" =================== function size: "+map.size());
     if (map.size() < 189) {
         var method = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Function.class, MethodHandles.lookup());
         MethodHandle addFunc = method.findStatic(Function.class, "addFunctionNotDeterministic", MethodType.methodType(void.class, String.class,
        int.class, int.class, int.class));
         addFunc.invoke("LOCK_MODE",214,0, org.h2.value.Value.INT);
     }
} catch (Throwable e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```